# Despite not getting any errors, my Tkinter GUI wont run. Why is that?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI that opens up a new window after pressing a button while destroying the last window. I'm not getting any errors but when I run  my program nothing comes up.

```
from Tkinter import *

def team():

    def table():
        table = Toplevel(contributers)
        contributers.destroy()
    def contributers():
        contributers = Toplevel(table)
        table.destroy()
    def firstpage():
        firstpage = Toplevel(letsbegin)
        letsbegin.destroy()
    def secondpage():
        secondpage = Toplevel(firstpage)
        firstpage.destroy()
    def leave():
        exit()

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Team Blue")
    label1 = label(menu, text="Team Blue", bg = "Yellow", fg="Black")
    button1 = button(menu, text="ENTER", width=15, bg="yellow", fg="Black", command =contributers)
    button2 = button(menu, text="Exit", bg="red", fg="white", command=leave)
    root.mainloop()
```

I just want this code to run

Comment: you have wrong indentions or you should run `team()`

Comment: it has to be `Label` and `Button` with upper `L` and upper `B`

Comment: what is `menu` ? You use it in `Label/Button` but you don't have this variable. You need `root` instead of `'menu`

Comment: you forgot `.pack()` to show widgets in window.

Comment: to close window use `root.destroy()` instead of `exit()`

Comment: you use the same name for function `table()` and variable `table = Toplevel()` which is local variable and other functions see only `table()` - so you try to destroy function in `table.destroy()`

Comment: you have so many mistakes that you should start learning `tkinter` from the beginning again.

Comment: @furas thanks I'm just trying to do a project that's due soon.

Comment: @furas how would you change my variables?

Comment: if you want to open new window after destroying `Tk()` window then you have to create new `Tk()` with new `mainloop()`. `Toplevel()` is used to create second/third window but it is used only when `Tk()` still exists. If you destroy `Tk()` then it will destroy also all `Toplevel` windows.

Comment: mostly `Toplevel()` is used without parameters (you have `contributers`, `table`, etc.). You can run `Toplevel()` with argument but it has to be window created with `Tk()`, not functions names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many mistakes which I mentioned in comments.

---

If you want to close one window and open new one then destroy first window - `root.destroy()` - and later use again `Tk()` to create new window and use again `mainloop()`.

I assign new window to global variable `root` so I can use almost the same code to close second window and open third one.

I use `global root` so variable `root` is not local variable but it is global and I have access (to window assigned to `root`) in other functions.

```
from Tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def open_first_window():
    global root

    root = Tk()
    label1 = Label(root, text="Team Brake 'Em")
    label1.pack()

    button1 = Button(root, text="Open Second Window", command=open_second_window)
    button1.pack()

    button2 = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    button2.pack()

    root.mainloop()

def open_second_window():
    global root

    root.destroy()

    root = Tk()
    label1 = Label(root, text="Second Window")
    label1.pack()

    button1 = Button(root, text="Open Third Window", command=open_third_window)
    button1.pack()

    button2 = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    button2.pack()

    root.mainloop()

def open_third_window():
    global root

    root.destroy()

    root = Tk()
    label1 = Label(root, text="Third Window")
    label1.pack()

    button2 = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    button2.pack()

    root.mainloop()

# --- main ---

open_first_window()
```

---

There is other popular method - don't destry window but remove all widgets and put new one. Widget `Frame` can be usful because you can put all widget in `Frame` and `Frame` put in Window and later you have to only remove `Frame` and put new `Frame` with new widgets.

```
from Tkinter import *

# --- function ---

def create_first_frame():
    global root
    global frame

    #frame.destroy()

    frame = Frame()
    frame.pack()

    label1 = Label(frame, text="Team Brake 'Em")
    label1.pack()

    button1 = Button(frame, text="Open Second Window", command=create_second_frame)
    button1.pack()

    button2 = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    button2.pack()

def create_second_frame():
    global root
    global frame

    frame.destroy()

    frame = Frame()
    frame.pack()

    label1 = Label(frame, text="Second Window")
    label1.pack()

    button1 = Button(frame, text="Open Third Window", command=create_third_frame)
    button1.pack()

    button2 = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    button2.pack()

def create_third_frame():
    global root
    global frame

    frame.destroy()

    frame = Frame()
    frame.pack()

    label1 = Label(frame, text="Third Window")
    label1.pack()

    button2 = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    button2.pack()

# --- main ---

root = Tk()
create_first_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because as you wrapped your whole  code inside the fuction name **team()**.

so, you have to call that method at appropriate position in order to run the program.

and please make sure the letter case as **label** fuction is written as **Label()** so does **button()** is **Button()**.

and also you have to use **root** in place of **menu**, then hopefully you see window.

pack the content according.